# SQL Query - Inner join matching with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have table which has the following `Columns  ID`, `Client ID`, `Provider ID`. I want to pull the records if the same `Client ID` and `Provider ID` combination exists more than once. (List both) My result should look like

```
Column ID  Client ID  Provider ID
   R1         C1         P1
   R2         C1         P1
   R3         C2         P2
   R4         C2         P2
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: could you show any effort?

Comment: How come the title of your question talk about "inner join" and your question is about doing a simple query on a single table without join? Please clarify this point.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work:

```
;
WITH X AS(    
  SELECT
  Count(*) over (partition by [Client ID], [Provider ID]) as [Cnt],
  *
  FROM
  YourDatabase..YourTable
  )
SELECT * FROM X WHERE [Cnt] >= 2
```

Comment: Another very good answer, which definitively needs an upvote. The use of window functions (`partition by`) is still far to less known. BTW, the double `..` is of course a mistake, and the `;` is not necessary. Also, I would set the upper open bracket down. I love the Allman bracket style.